# Require.js adds ".scripts" suffix to the file name

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to learn require.js. I've copied a html from [requirejs.org tutorial](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#add) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sample Project</title>
        <!-- data-main attribute tells require.js to load
             scripts/main.js after require.js loads. -->
        <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Sample Project</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've also created a file scripts/main.js and copied requrie.js to scripts/. I'm getting this error in my browser:

```
main.scripts    GET 404 text/html require.js:1903
```

Why does it get *main.scripts*  not *main.js*?

**EDIT**
Problem solved after downloading require.js again. Please, close this issue.

Comment: RequireJS does not routinely add `.scripts` to the name of the modules it is requested to load. If this is happening in your case, then there's something you're not showing in your question that is interfering.

Comment: You should be able to delete your own question, since it has only one answer and the answer has a negative score. I've put a close vote on it but 4 other people will have to vote to close before it is closed, and that can take a while. If you can't delete, you could flag it and explain.

Answer (score -1):

RequireJS loads all code relative to a baseUrl. The baseUrl is normally set to the same directory as the script used in a data-main attribute for the top level script to load for a page. The data-main attribute is a special attribute that require.js will check to start script loading.  Follow below link -

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

Comment: explain votedown. Looks like you don't want to read complete API documentation and want to raise useless questions

Comment: Vote down is not from me.

Comment: Problem is not with directory but with the suffix. My project's structure: project-directory/
project.html
 scripts/
  main.js
  require.js